# Is it possible to redirect a user to avoid showing an AJAX batch processing error?

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm trying to allow users to cancel their accounts without requiring e-mail confirmation as [described in this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/32427/5147).

Currently, when I use the following code, the user account is cancelled properly, but the AJAX display shows a nasty error.

```
  else {
    // Cancel the account
    user_cancel($form_state['values'], $account->uid, $form_state['values']['user_cancel_method']);
```

[image: ajax error]

I tried adding `drupal_goto('user/logout');` after `user_cancel()`, but this immediately logs the user out and the account is not cancelled.  What I would like to do is cancel the account, log the user out, and somehow not display this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the error-- I had a custom rule that sent an e-mail to the admin when the account was cancelled.  By deleting this rule, the error disappears and the user is logged out properly.