# Is it possible to allow users with Javascript disabled to cancel their accounts?

Tags: users

I have a Drupal 7 site where users have permission to cancel their accounts.  Most users are able to cancel their accounts without trouble, but some users (at least some of whom do not have Javascript enabled because they are on extremely old mobile phones, etc.) are unable to cancel their account because doing so takes them to an AJAX batch processing page that doesn't work on their devices.

Is there an alternate way to allow such users to cancel their accounts, or am I stuck doing this manually?

EDIT: I realized that the cause of this issue is my use of [the code in this solution to remove the e-mail confirmation requirement](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/32427/5147), so this issue probably only affects my site.

Comment: Frankly, this sounds like a core bug to me. Have you checked the queue? I would definitely open an issue if one doesn't already exist. We should support progressive enhancement, IMO.

Comment: Sounds more like a contrib module issue, I think.  What contrib modules do you have installed? I just went through the process on 7.23-dev and it works fine with JavaScript disabled. Do you happen to know which url they are re-directed to?

Comment: The URL looks like this: `/en/batch?op=start&id=2659`

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to help here, but I can not reproduce.  By default, in 7-dev and 7.22, the link to cancel an account is not included in a users account edit page.  How are you displaying the link to the user? Did you add a menu item, alter the user edit form, custom module, or ...?

Comment: Even though this indeed sounds a contrib problem,  Batch API should work without JS, via meta refresh.

Comment: @chx I agree, but why would batch api even be used for an individual user cancelling their own account?

Comment: Updated my answer- this issue is due to custom code for disabling cancellation e-mail confirmation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in core. Batch processing is not supposed to require JavaScript enabled. See [this question and accepted answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50996/how-does-the-batch-api-work-internally) if you don't want to read the code itself.