# How can I redirect users after they cancel their accounts?

Tags: redirection

Is there a way redirect users after they cancel their accounts?  I've configured my site to allow [users to cancel their accounts without e-mail confirmation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32413/how-can-i-allow-users-to-cancel-their-accounts-without-requiring-e-mail-confirma), but I want to be able to redirect them to a "goodbye" page to reassure them that their account was in fact cancelled.

In `user_cancel()`, though, account cancellation is performed with the Batch API.  I tried adding a `drupal_goto()` after the call to `batch_set($batch)`, but this forces the goto and the batch processing is not performed.

How can I redirect non-admin users after they cancel their accounts?

Answer (score 1):

There are two fine ways to do it :

1. With [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) : If you have installed it already then you must use this. Select the event "After a user account has been deleted". Check the conditions you want and add action "Page Redirect".
2. With [Hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_delete/7) : Write a [hook_user_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_delete/7) and add [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

You mention batch and the profile/cancel form.

Taking a look at the [Batch API docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/180528), we see that when called via form, FAPI will handle the redirect.  Leading to the conclusion that you could add a submission handler with `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` for the cancellation form and set `$form_state['redirect']`.

This would probably be advantageous over `hook_user_delete` &| `drupal_goto`, as higher weighted modules may get ignored.  You could use rules but unless you're already using it elsewhere that's a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong [user_cancel_confirm_form_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_cancel_confirm_form_submit/7) tries redirecting user to profile page after account cancelation which might end up throwing page not found. Looks like $form_state['redirect'] needs to be overridden in custom submit handler.